# How to access a map<text,text> from Cassandra inside a resultset in Scala?

Tags: scala, cassandra

So, basically, I'm using Spark to connect to a Cassandra database who have a column of type "map<text, text>". I can read the values from others columns, but not this one. Basically, my code is:

```
   val query = "SELECT * FROM mydatabase.mytable;"
    val conf = spark.sparkContext.getConf
    val connector = CassandraConnector.apply(conf);
    val session = connector.openSession();
    val rs = session.execute(query)  //resultset

    val rows = rs.all().map { row =>
    val pk = row.getString("pk")
    val column2= row.getString("column2")
    val column3 = row.getInt("column3")
    val mapColumn = row.getMap[String, String]("mapColumn")
    Row(pk , column2, column3 , mapColumn )
    }
```

I can read the 3 other columns, except the Map one. Can't find the solution online. How can I read the map type values?

This is the error i get when i try to run

> error: overloaded method value getMap with alternatives: [KeyT, ValueT](x$1: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlIdentifier, x$2: Class[KeyT], x$3: Class[ValueT])java.util.Map[KeyT,ValueT]  [KeyT, ValueT](x$1: String, x$2: Class[KeyT], x$3: Class[ValueT])java.util.Map[KeyT,ValueT]  [KeyT, ValueT](x$1: Int, x$2: Class[KeyT], x$3: Class[ValueT])java.util.Map[KeyT,ValueT] cannot be applied to (String) val mapColumn= row.getMap("mapColumn")

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all: there's no such method `getMap("columnName")` but there is the following one:

```scala
getMap("columnName",
  classOf[String], // key class
  classOf[String]) // value class
```

Comment: It didn't worked to me. However i managed to make it using: 
`val mapObject = row.getObject("mapColumn")
            val mapColumn = mapObject.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]].toMap`

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Any error?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it using:

`val mapObject = row.getObject("mapColumn")`

`val mapColumn = mapObject.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]].toMap`

Registering in case it can help someone.